# draw using wxPython, how fast fill all pixels?

Tags: python, graphics, drawing, wxpython

I am learning how to do gui using Python and in particularly wxPython. I want to write next program to draw fuzzy balls on blue background. I assign weights to points around the click coordinates from 0 to 1, in the middle it is 1 and it gradually decreases if we go far away from click point. 
My problem that code that I have written is toooo slow, it takes several seconds to update picture. I can see how program updated picture from left to right.

I draw each pixel using `dc.DrawPoint(i,j)` where `dc = wx.PaintDC(self)` in my class that represents main window. The size of the window is 600x400 pixels.
My question is how accelerate drawing process. Is there methods to do that?

Edit:
okay, I understand that I should not draw each pixel.
How to use bitmap to draw?

code of my program:

```
import wx
import random
import numpy

class FuzzyBalls(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(600, 400))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnPaint)
    self.Centre()
    self.Show(True)

def OnPaint(self, event):
    dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
    w, h = self.GetSize()
    b = 20
    x0 = 300
    y0 = 200
    eta = 0.0001
    panel_pos = self.ScreenToClient(wx.GetMousePosition())
    print panel_pos
    x0, y0 = panel_pos
    field = numpy.zeros(w*h).reshape((h,w))
    field = numpy.matrix(field)
    for i in xrange(h):
        for j in xrange(w):
            field[i,j] = numpy.exp(-eta*((i-y0)**2 + (j-x0)**2))
    z = field.sum(axis = 1).sum(axis = 0)[0,0]
    field = field/z
    n = 29000
    for i in xrange(w):
        for j in xrange(h):
            r = int(n*255*field[j,i])
            if r > 253: 
                r = 253
            dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.Colour(r,r,b)))
            dc.DrawPoint(i,j)

app = wx.App()
FuzzyBalls(None, -1, 'Points')
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: "I draw each pixel" I THINK WE'VE FOUND THE PROBLEM...

Answer (score 2):

Never ever *ever* draw each pixel, *especially* not to the display. Draw on an off-screen bitmap, then blit to the display. Draw every single frame you can get away with beforehand, so that you never need to draw again for the life of the program.

Comment: Create a wxBitmap of the appropriate size, use a wxMemoryDC to draw to it, then use wxDC::Blit to blit from it.

Comment: I'm just googling for this, found this answer, and I'd also love to see an example of this technique. Why can't you show it?

Comment: @MightyPork: Because I've never actually done it in wx; I simply described how it would be done in almost any modern graphics toolkit.